# Large open source repositories

Tags: open-source, github, repository, codeplex, sourceforge

I'm in need of a large repository of open source projects (around 1000 or more, the programming languages don't matter, but a good mix will be nice) for my research work. I thought of downloading projects from Github/SourceForge/Codeplex, but I cannot find the right API's to do it.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to download projects from the aforementioned websites (Like, how Twitter allows us to grab tweets from the public time-line)? Or any other place where I can get a good mix of open source projects?

Comment: ftp://ftp.gnu.org is another good source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much all open source repositories allow remote access via the appropriate source control provider - so the simplest way to download all the projects from Github would be to use git. Even if there's no API for it, all you need to do is find the right URL for each repo, and scraping something like the ["explore"](https://github.com/repositories) page should be easy.

Comment: I'm looking for around a 1000 projects. "Explore" has very limited numbers.

Comment: @Gooner: Do a search then (https://github.com/search) and page through the results.

Comment: Sounds cool. I shall wait for a few others to pop in their opinions before accepting the answers though. Thanks!

Comment: @Gooner: Of course there are other options beyond Github too - but many of them have multiple source control types, which would make it slightly harder. For example, Google Code supports svn, git and hg. It's fairly easy to find them though: http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aJava (etc)

Comment: I thought GoogleCode used svn only! This sounds interesting. Let me check it out.

Comment: @Gooner: Nope, we started supported hg a while ago, and git just recently (start of August, I think).

Comment: That's very cool, I'll check out both and see what suits my use case best!